# Hybridauth Google connect error "accessNotConfigured"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, hybridauth

I have an issue that when i try to connect to Google via hybridauth

after a successful authentication, i get the following error :

> accessNotConfigured
>
> Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or
>   there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API
>   key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the
>   Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

I followed the configuration instruction, as listed in the [docs](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Google.html)

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems that all i needed to do is to enable the google+ API, on the google console